# Can I change the style of Android Button after Initializing the set content view?

Tags: java, android

I want to display different style of button in android Button View depending upon the string value , can i able to do this programmatically?

Can I use set style condition programmatically, even though I set setTextAppearance its not reflecting in the view?

```
  private Button dynakey[]= new Button[9];//8 buttons       
        //Parse the values of buttons 
        try {
            String sButtonString="";
            JSONArray jArrayButton = 
            ResponseUIObject.getJSONArray("BUTTON");
            for(int k=0;k<8;k++) {
                int ID=k+1;
                String dynakeyID = "dynakey"+(ID);
                int resID  = getResources().getIdentifier(dynakeyID, "id", getPackageName());
                dynakey[ID] =(Button) findViewById(resID);
                sButtonString= jArrayButton.getString(k-0);
                 //Set Enable or Disable logic here
                if ((ID% 2) == 0) {
                    // number is even its a right side button //Change style of button depending upon the value
                    if(sButtonString.trim().length() == 0) {
                        //If string is not null or not empty then Enable the button else not
                        dynakey[ID].setTextAppearance(this, R.style.RightDisableDynakeyButton);
                    }else{
                        dynakey[ID].setTextAppearance(this, R.style.RightEnableDynakeyButton);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // number is odd its a left side button //Change style of button depending upon the value
                    if(sButtonString.trim().length() ==0) {
                        //If string is not null or empty then Enable the button else not
                        dynakey[ID].setTextAppearance(this, R.style.LeftDisableDynakeyButton);
                    }else{
                        dynakey[ID].setTextAppearance(this, R.style.LeftEnableDynakeyButton);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This form of `setTextAppearance()` you use is deprecated. Change your code to something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    dynakey[ID].setTextAppearance(this, R.style.LeftDisableDynakeyButton);
} else {
    dynakey[ID].setTextAppearance(R.style.LeftDisableDynakeyButton);
}
```

Since API 23 `setTextAppearance(styleId)` was introduced.  
Try it.  
**Edit** for your code:  
(1) This line:  
`private Button dynakey[]= new Button[9];`  
creates an array of 9 buttons and not 8 as the comment states.  
(2) You apply the changes inside a `try` block (I can't see a `catch` block), so any errors are not propagated. Could it be that the ids of the buttons are incorrect?  
(3) Post your styles and xml

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_button_gray" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_button_colored" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

Now add this selector to button as background

```
       <Button
        android:id = "@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Now in code

```
if(sButtonString.trim().length() == 0) {
 dynakey[ID].setEnabled(true)
} else {
dynakey[ID].setEnabled(false)
}
```

Comment: I am using styles  for the button and i want to change the style of the buttons